# Vue.js - How to import a filter into a component from a separate file?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, es6-modules

I have a vue-cli project with a vue.js component (MyComponent.vue).

I'm trying to import a filter (MyFilter.vue) into the component from a separate file.

It works if I export the filter as an object, but not if I export it as a function. What am I missing?

WORKS

```js
//MyFilter.vue
<script>
  export default {
    capitalize: function(val){
      return val.toUpperCase();
    }
    //export filter as object
  }
</script>


//MyComponent.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <p><input v-model="myInput"></p>
    <p>{{myInput | capitalize}}</p>
  </div>
 </template>

<script>
  import Capitalize from './MyFilter';    
  //This import works

  export default {
    filters: {
      capitalize: Capitalize.capitalize       
      //This filter works
    },
   
  data: function() {
    return {
      myInput: 'test'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

DOES NOT WORK

```js
//MyFilter.vue
<script>
  export default function(val){
    return val.toUpperCase();
    //Export an function does NOT work
  }
</script>

//MyComponent.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <p><input v-model="myInput"></p>
    <p>{{myInput | capitalize}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Capitalize from './MyFilter';    
  //This import does NOT work

  export default {
    filters: {
      capitalize: Capitalize       
      //This filter does NOT work
    },

    data: function() {
      return {
        myInput: 'test'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

When the page loads I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'functional' of undefined"

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens, but you can define a filter globally in the main.js file (or wherever you initialize `new Vue`) -- see [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html#ad)

Comment: Yeah. I know that's one option. So is passing in the object. I just stumbled into this particular issue and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong :)

Comment: It's working just fine. Check this sandbox  https://codesandbox.io/s/xrl18964np

Comment: So, it's got nothing to do with the way you are exporting/importing your filter

Comment: Why do you think it's the way you are importing your filter?  That error doesn't mention filters or "Capitalize".

Comment: @zero298 - because just flipping that filter text and filter property and nothing else breaks and fixes it

Comment: @Prashant - Thank you! I noticed that your MyFilter file was .js and mine was .vue - I changed mine to .js and it worked. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference, the reason this does not work is that the filter is defined within a script tag in a Vue (*.vue) file.

```
// MyFilter.vue

<script>
    export default function(val) {
        return val.toUpperCase();
    }
</script>
```

Vue files are for single file components and as default export from within the script tag in a Vue file, we usually emit a component options object.

When Vue tries to setup hot-reloading for MyFilter.vue file, it expects a component option. Checks whether the component is functional in the options. `options.functional`. And, in this case, the options is undefined. So, we get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'functional' of undefined

So, the lesson to learn is that Vue files are for single file components, anything else, plain-old JS.